# how to prevent from changing tab by mouse click

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

my question could be silly but I'm trying to **disable changing of tabs by mouse click** in `JTabbedPane`. I searched on google but didn't found any helpful answer. I tried to add empty `MouseListener` but still I can change the tab on mouse click.

My Code is as follows:

```
public JTabbedPane createTabbedPane()
{
    JTabbedPane pane=new JTabbedPane();
    pane.addTab("tab1",panel1);
    pane.addTab("tab2",panel2);
    pane.addTab("tab3",panel3);
    pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter());
    return pane;
}
```

I also tried this one:

```
public JTabbedPane createTabbedPane()
{
    JTabbedPane pane=new JTabbedPane();
    pane.addTab("tab1",panel1);
    pane.addTab("tab2",panel2);
    pane.addTab("tab3",panel3);
    pane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
    {
        @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
    return pane;
}
```

If any one have any idea about how to do this please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use getComponents() of pane and try and error if you can find a Mouselistener, that you can remove. I know that if you've got an own Tab Component you can overwrite the mouselistener (it's in the foreground, so the selectListener won't work), though a small border is still clickable.

Answer (score 2):

You can block changing tabs by mouse with help of `ChangeListener` like next:

```
final JTabbedPane pane = new JTabbedPane();
pane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        pane.setSelectedIndex(HOLD_INDEX);
    }
});
```

`HOLD_INDEX` is index of tab selected programatically.

Here when you try to select another tab it will be reselected to `HOLD_INDEX`.

Comment: Does the ChangeListener only get User-Input? Or is selecting Tabs completely deactivated then?

Comment: thanks alex it worked for me I also tried to enable the tab by taking index of the tab and disabling other but it didn't worked in changelistener. But thanks a lot.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale, `it worked for me` - then its time you start accepting answers. You have asked 20 questions and not once have you accepted an answer. Accepting answers is the proper way to say "thanks for the help" and tell everybody in the forum that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you could try...

### You Could

Set the tabs you don't want selected to disabled...

```
pane.setEnabled(indexOfTab, false);
```

### You Could

Supply your own [`SingleSelectionModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SingleSelectionModel.html) from which you can control which tabs can be selected

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility could be to override the `addMouseListener(...)` with an empty implementation to prevent any mouse interaction. Sample code could be as follows:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane() {
    public synchronized void addMouseListener(MouseListener l) { };
};
```